# Checking String for enum in Java

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, java

Write a Java method to check if a given string matches any value in a given enum.

Your method will take two parameters, one a string and one an enum, and return `true` if the string representation of any of the enum's elements matches the given string, or `false` otherwise. Note that your method should still function normally if the String parameter is `null`, and that you aren't allowed to use any external libraries.

Test cases:

```java
public enum E { A, B, C; }

public enum F { X, Y, Z; }

check("a", E.A); // is false (because "A" is uppercase) 
check(null, E.A); // is false
check("C", E.A); // is true
check("X", F.X); // is true
check(null, F.X); // is false
check("y", F.X); // is false
```

The method has access (as a solver correctly understood) to a generic type E that has the only bound that "E extends Enum(E)".

Reference implementation (Ungolfed):

```java
boolean <E extends Enum<E>> check(String s, E e){
    for(E ex : e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants())
        if(ex.toString().equals(s)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Another possible implementation (due to a solution) is (Ungolfed):

```java
public static <E extends Enum<E>> boolean check(String s, E e){
    return java.util.stream.Stream.of(e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()).anyMatch(x->x.name().equals(s));
}
```

What I'm looking for is the shortest thing I could put after return (or, as a solutor did, after "(String s,E e)->)".

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins!

Comment: What should the method _do_? With the current spec, always returning `true` is allowed.

Comment: I'll edit, probably the request on parameters is too restrictive, I'll also add an example.

Comment: Single-language challenges are also discouraged here. Unless the challenge only makes sense for Java, you should allow all languages.

Comment: In this case, I'm starting from a Java enum so, unless another language can deal with a Java class, I don't see why I should allow other languages. (Sorry for my obstinacy, but I'm new here and I wanted this to solve a more practical than theoretical problem).

Comment: Okay, now I get what the challenge is about. Because it's so focused, I think it would be received better as a [tag:tips] question that asks for golfing advice, like "I want to check whether the name of a Java enum value matches a given string, is there a shorter way than this?"

Comment: Ok, tried to edit in that sense. May I know if there are some more not clear points left?

Comment: So is the code to check whether a given string is found in an enum?

Comment: The task could be described in the main text more explicitly, e.g. "The method should return `true` if the string is equal to the string representation of any value in the enum class, and `false` otherwise. `null` strings should also result in `false`." Remove the "shortest code wins" part too; [tag:tips] questions are not competitions.

Comment: Edited as suggested. Thank you.

Comment: Can we assume that the enum class will be `E`?

Comment: I prefer if you don't make assumptions on the class `E` because I'm going to use it within a context with generics.

Comment: >I prefer if you don't make assumptions on the class E
That is a bit self-contradictory, as looking at your reference method you _do use a literal E type_ at least twice there. You should then declare it as:  <E extends Enum> void check(String s,E e) instead.

Comment: Otherwise i can not see why E.valueOf() would be incorrect to do, or why do we need a second argument at all (as that is no different of how your check method operates).

Comment: 1. The words "*given*" and "*enum*" are both somewhat ambiguous. If you really intend for the signature of the method to be `boolean c(String, E)` then "*given*" means two different things in the first sentence of the question. Other interpretations would lead to signatures `boolean c(String, Enum)` or `boolean c(String, Class<? extends Enum>)`. The comment above that you "*prefer if you don't make assumptions on the class `E`*" suggests that you want the second or third signature, but the reference implementation uses the first. 2. It's confusing to ask for return values of `True` and `False`

Comment: I'll try to edit it.

Comment: There are now two reference implementations with different signatures. In my opinion that's adding to the confusion, not reducing it.

Comment: I don't get where the problem is. This method takes a string and a variable that must be an instance of some enum and returns true iff the string represents an instance of the same enum as the example given by the second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Java 8, 86 bytes

```java
(String s,E e)->java.util.stream.Stream.of(E.values()).anyMatch(x->x.name().equals(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#jY7BbsIwEETv@YpRTrYUzAekRQKU3jhxrHpY3AVMHceNbQRCfHvqlqhIVQ/sZVezuzPPtL7rIw50JJWisWqbnI6mc2phXsaxLgp2qUWDC@YVFhWWNa5Z9WljjYa2FAJWZBwuRYFc4yJEirkdO/OONq/FOvbG7V7fQP0uyHyNse5hT7ebCk1O6jrL5GbQe9YfeMYwOiBUDVhOZnfuEHumVq1vrduKRh3JJg5CSkXuvKKo9@I0mZ2Uo5aFVPyZyAYRpBzqX5D1OUTO/ykqn5OideInXJH39ixKKjOZmktZYzqFCdhmD4bYsKaUh3JefqvJe@41BZZ41Nola//zfhht@Rct9un2fS2K6/AF)

Comment: My experience with java Stream is that it works by some odd magic, but it works so I won't question it and hopefully my code doesn't fall apart. Java really isn't my thing.

Comment: Taking that you do E.values() (which implies E to be of a known Enum type), you can now remove E e from the lambda signature, as it is not really used anywhere.

Comment: @zeppelin No, I can't, because the challenge states "Your method will take two parameters, one a string and one an enum".

Comment: @Mego `E` should be `Enum`, as this is supposed to take in any enum, not just `E`

Comment: Yep, because it implies that E is _<E extends Enum>_ instead (through OP failed to formulate that correctly), but in this case your E.values() code won't compile or work.

Comment: The test cases imply that the function should take a value, not an Enum class.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 4+, 96 bytes

```
boolean c(String a,Enum e){for(E f:values())if(f.toString().equals(a))return true;return false;}
```

Test code:

```
public enum E {
    A,B,C,D,E,F;
    public static void main(String[]a) {
        System.out.println(E.c("a",E));
        System.out.println(E.c("B",E));
        System.out.println(E.c("d",E));
        System.out.println(E.c("C",E));
        System.out.println(E.c("D",E));
        System.out.println(E.c("e",E));
        System.out.println(E.c("F",E));
    }
    boolean c(String a,Enum e){for(E f:values())if(f.toString().equals(a))return true;return false;}
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
false
true
true
false
true
```